# Apache Allowoverride FileInfo Security Handling

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I would like to know the security issues by using "Allowoverride FileInfo" in httpd.conf file, which allows htaccess file(my htaccess file just makes redirections which are defined in the zend2). I am using zend framework 2.x for my project (just like some shopping cart site).

```
I have researched and I got the following information.

 1. Better to place "Allowoverride FileInfo" inside "Directory" directive for better      performance.
 2. Use "AccessFileName .config" instead of allowing .htaccess we can use .config, which might help some way security.
 3. Just copiying the htaccess code to httpd.conf file(for which there is no security risk, as "Allowoverride None" is used).
```

But nothing about the security issue, which is the main concern.

```
Could somebody help me with information if .htaccess file is used.

1. What are the security measures I have to take care ?.
2. Is there a chance of intrusion?.
```

Thanks,
Dilip.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. As a start to an answer, as documented at [core: Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html), the FileInfo permission does the following:

> FileInfo
>
> Allow use of the directives controlling document types (ErrorDocument, ForceType, LanguagePriority, SetHandler, SetInputFilter, SetOutputFilter, and mod_mime Add* and Remove* directives), document meta data (Header, RequestHeader, SetEnvIf, SetEnvIfNoCase, BrowserMatch, CookieExpires, CookieDomain, CookieStyle, CookieTracking, CookieName), mod_rewrite directives (RewriteEngine, RewriteOptions, RewriteBase, RewriteCond, RewriteRule), mod_alias directives (Redirect, RedirectTemp, RedirectPermanent, RedirectMatch), and Action from mod_actions.

So if any of those directives could be misused by whoever might control `.htaccess` files in your directory tree, you might have a problem. E.g. if you delegate control over parts of your directory tree, you should trust those administrators to use all those directives.

But also note that in general, doing configuration from the conf files is strongly preferred to the use of `.htaccess`.

But if you have good reasons for using `.htaccess`, and have effective control over all the content in the whole directory tree, or at least the `.htaccess` files, then it seems that `AllowOverride FileInfo` shouldn't add much security exposure, so long as you use each of the directives you choose to use in a safe manner.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a script for web page security (home made or payd for (I make them) to track page views and from what ip and time, or use your logs, you can also make authorization files (i make them and could help you) and make it auto ban upon incorrect login attempts, for other things (other than web pages) like ftp you can use ssl or rsa security certificates that change with each attempt same goes for vpn certificates but its really what you need it for, by default .htaccess files should be set to read only and never allow-override (using your apache2 conf file). I hope this answers your question if not maybe tell me more about what esactly you wish to protect, im currently making a script that will email you upon a breech or access of a certain file / page from an unauthorized user.